# Transfer function in recursive form

Tags: integral-transforms

To get transfer function in recursive form, I tried this:

```
Normal[ZTransform[
 y[n] == x[n] - (1/4) y[n - 2],
 n, z,
 TransformPairs -> {y[n] :> Y[z], x[n] :> X[z]}
]]
```

And I expect this solution:

$$
Y[z] = X[z] - \frac{Y[z]}{4z^2}
$$

But I only got notification about error

> OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option TransformPairs for ZTransform.
>
> General::stop: Further output of OptionValue::nodef will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: ASAIK `TransformPairs` is not an option for `ZTranform`?

Comment: `TransformPairs` is not an option for anything, being a nonexistent symbol. It is hard to know how exactly OP expected this to work, or what `Normal` is supposed to do. Perhaps something like `ZTransform[y[n] == x[n] - (1/4) y[n - 2], n, z] /. {ZTransform[y[n], n, z] -> Y[z], 
  ZTransform[x[n], n, z] -> X[z]}` would be correct. I really don't know.